# iOS 8: When App in Background CBCentralManager Delegate Method didDiscoverPeripheral, didConnectPeripheral, didFailToConnectPeripheral not called

Tags: ios, ios8, background-process, core-bluetooth

I am using Xcode 6 with iOS 8. I am trying to search and connect bluetooth device when app is running in Background. I am using corebluetooth framework. I have added bluetooth-central and bluetooth-peripheral using Xcode capabilities option.

Code:

**Appdelegate.h**

```
@interface WSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *savedUUID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *CBCM;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
    self.savedUUID= [defaults stringForKey:@"uuid"];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        NSLog(@"Object Created::::");
         self.CBCM = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];


        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

}


- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    printf("Status of CoreBluetooth central manager changed \n");

    if(self.CBCM.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        //okay your good to go and can now scan
        //  NSLog(@"your good to go and can now scan");
        NSLog(@"Searching for Device::::");
        NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:self.savedUUID];//where savedUUID is the string version of the NSUUID you've saved somewhere

        NSArray *peripherals = [self.CBCM retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[uuid]];

        for(CBPeripheral *periph in peripherals)
        {
            [self.CBCM connectPeripheral:periph options:nil];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Unable to use CentralManager methods so print out the central.state and find out why
        NSLog(@"Unable to use CentralManager methods so print out the central state and find out why:::%d",self.CBCM.state);
    }


}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSLog(@"Peripheral Found::::%@",peripheral);

}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {

    printf("Connection to peripheral with UUID successfull\r\n");

}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    printf("Connection to peripheral with UUID Fail,didFailToConnectPeripheral\r\n");
    printf("Error code was %s\r\n",[[error description] cStringUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy]);

}
```

didDiscoverPeripheral method is not called so I am using saved uuid of last connected device but it is not connecting and not calling delegates method didConnectPeripheral and  didFailToConnectPeripheral.
So how to solve this problem and connect with bluetooth while app is running in Background?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to confirm that retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers returns a CBPeripheral?

Comment: yes, I have already done it and also printed the value "array (
    "<CBPeripheral: 0x16571e70, identifier = 67E88C4A-C683-D90E-D194-0B2C35B3E668, name = Walkingspree 835F18, state = disconnected>"
)" but still it is not working.

Comment: Is that peripheral advertising?  Also you shouldn't initialise your CBManager in a `beginBackgroundTask` block. You should just initialise it directly

Comment: No, Peripheral is not advertising. Let me try it.

Comment: I have tried and it shows "CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn" is true but still not working.

Comment: If the peripheral is not advertising how do you expect to be able to connect to it?

Comment: I mean to say that I have already tried that and peripheral is being advertised successfully but still it does not connect.

Comment: Do you have a pending connect before your app enters the background?

Comment: No sir, There is no pending connect. Do you know any tutorial or example which do same thing like search and connect Bluetooth Device in Background?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't search in the background, you would just call connect and then the connection will happen in the background when the peripheral comes into range.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a BackgroundTask to scan for peripherals in the background.

1) When creating your CBCentralManager make sure you are specifying an option for **CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey**.

```
  myCentralManager =
    [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil
     options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:
     @"myCentralManagerIdentifier" }];
```

See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW6

2) Look for UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey in the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method's launchOptions:

```
NSArray *centralManagerIdentifiers =
    launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];
```

This is used to restore your central manager. (Will be the same name for the key in 1).

3) Make sure you implement willRestoreState in your CBCentralManagerDelegate. See the documentation listed above.